# How generate documentation on maven?

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I am new with Maven, and now I am trying to generate the project documentation. Until now, I find that I only need to run the command

```
mvn site
```

or

```
mvn clean site
```

and thats all this command will generate the folder site inside target folder, and does it but also  should generate some files main is index.html and here its the problem, command doesn't generetate those files, only the folders

[image]

I will hope the file index.html looks like

[image]

and those folders have files, like images and files *.css,
So I don't know if I need to do some steps before?
Also If you can recommend me a tutorial or documentation about it, thanks

Comment: Best start here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/index.html The other question is: What would you like to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, I am following a Tutorial and the section specify that after I run the command I should find the file index.html and it should look like the image I update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found  the correct way to do it, because the tutorial that I was following it isn't full descriptive, it is why I'm confused. But I found the guide of maven to do it. Check it here [Creating a site](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-site.html). So I need to create the folder site inside src path, and this folder should contain file site.xml which relates the different components of the site, those could be developed in different document types, in the page there are some links to know how to do it. So this is mine site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <body>
        <menu name="Overview">
            <item name="Introduction" href="index.html"/>
            <item name="Goals" href="plugin-info.html"/>
        </menu>
    </body>
</project>
```

And I use the xDoc type, so I create xdoc folder inside site, this contains all the files related in site.xml (index.xml and plgin-info.xml in example)

[image: folder structure]  [image: files related in site.xml]

so after that run the command `mvn site` and got this in targe\site

[image: taget folder]

[image: site]